# 4 extra vertical pixels?

Tags: html, css

I've got a header element that's constructed as follows:

```
<div id="header">
  <div id="title">
    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Element17 Photography">
  </div>
  <div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="togglelink grey2white button" data-block="albums" id="togglealbums">Albums</li>
      <li class="togglelink grey2white button" data-block="about" id="toggleabout">About Me</li>
      <li class="togglelink grey2white button" data-block="contact" id="togglecontact">Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS to go with is as follows:

```
#header {left:10px; top:10px; position:absolute; height:80px; display:table;}
#title {display:table-cell; height:80px; margin:0; padding:0 20px 0 0; border-right:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.75);}
#menu {display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; margin:0; padding:0; height:80px;}
#menu ul {list-style-type:none; margin:0 0 0 20px; padding:0; font-size:0.75em;}
```

I've specified an `80px` height on basically every element, and yet in Chrome it's rendering at `84px` in height.  You can see it live here: [www.element17.com](http://www.element17.com).

Why is this happening?

Comment: Is it a problem visually or are you just bothered by the extra pixels as a developer? To be honest I can't really see any problems with it.

Comment: The latter, mostly.  Makes my OCD flare up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the `<img>` is a replaced inline element which sits on its **[baseline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_%28typography%29)** by default.

The image itself has a height of `80px` and the extra vertical gap belongs to the line height reserved characters (descenders like: g j p q y).

You could simply fix that by aligning the image by [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) property with a value other than `baseline`:

```css
img {
    vertical-align: middle; /* top or bottom */
}
```

For further information you can refer to [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/why-an-image-inside-a-div-has-an-extra-space-below-the-image/5804278#5804278).

Answer (score 2):

instead of using

```
 display:table-cell
```

you can use

```
 display:block

#title {
    display: block;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 20px 0 0;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
}
```

You can find [Detailed answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19698333/table-cell-box-model-extra-width-and-height)

you can also remove white space in the markup by font-size:0px;

```
#title
{
    display: table-cell;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 20px 0 0;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
    font-size: 0px;
}
```

Comment: font-size:0px doesn't remove white space in the markup, it merely hides its presence. The better fix for that would probably be to just find and remove the offending whitespace.