# CSS: Unable to set padding-bottom = 0 in a Photo-DIV

Tags: css, responsive-design, padding

```
 <div id="container">
 <img src="photo.png" alt="foobar" class="myphoto />
 </div>

 #container {
   padding 0;
   border: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
   width: 100%;
   }

 #container .myphoto {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  }
```

When I do this, there's always a blank field between the photo and the bottom-border of the container-DIV (~ 3px). It looks like:

```
 #container {
  padding: 0 0 3px 0;
  }
```

Is there a trick?

Comment: Can you do a jsfiddle?

Comment: add `#container .myphoto {display:block;}`

Comment: @Pete Way ahead of you! (by like 10 whole seconds!)

Comment: possible duplicate of [4 extra vertical pixels?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510403/4-extra-vertical-pixels)

Comment: @HashemQolami Don't get me wrong this could be found to be a dupe but for that one? The title of that could mean anything....

Comment: @Ruddy `there's always a blank field between the photo and the bottom-border of the container` That's exactly the `4 extra vertical pixels` in my posted link.

Comment: @HashemQolami You clearly didn't read what I said. If I had this problem I wouldn't search "4 extra vertical pixels". Its a very precise title name isn't it? It maybe the same problem but its not the best title to be found in search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: block;` to the img.

### CSS:

```
 #container .myphoto {
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     display: block;
 }
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/FHLNZ/)

Comment: @Christoph Yup, it happens but you learn from it and never run into the same problem again!