# 3 spans in href with vertical align to img

Tags: html, css, href

I do have a div like this:

```
<div class="frontend-shop-cart-left">
   <a href="#">
      <img src="#" style=" display:inline; vertical-align: middle;height:60px; width:60px; " />
   </a>
   <a href="#">
      <span style="margin-left: 15px; font-size: 14px;" >1</span>
   </a>
</div>
```

The text ist vertical align to middle and it looks good. But if I am going to add two spans in the second href the rendering is bad.

It looks like this:

```
|-------|
| image | 1
|       |
|-------| 
 2 3
```

But I want this.

```
|-------|
| image | 1
|       | 2 3
|-------|
```

My html code is like this:

```
<div class="frontend-shop-cart-left">
   <a href="#">
      <img src="#" style=" display:inline; vertical-align: middle;height:60px; width:60px; " />
   </a>
   <a href="#">
      <span style="margin-left: 15px; font-size: 14px;" >1</span> <br/>
      <span style="margin-left: 15px; font-size: 14px;" >2</span>
      <span style="font-size: 14px;" >3</span>
   </a>
</div>
```

What is wrong with my CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the anchor tag is not a block element. You can either add `display:inline-block` to your anchor tags, or float the first or both anchor tags to the left.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/qfx5xt0b/1/

Answer (score 1):

Let the `img` element control the left flow using `float: left`

```
<img src="#" style="float: left; ....
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rahilwazir/wL6ja3rm/)

Comment: You shouldn't really float inline elements;

Answer (score 1):

Display the anchors as inline-block elements and align them vertically by `vertical-align: middle;` as follows:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsbin.com/tutuqosazovu/3/edit)**

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Also specifying `vertical-align` for the image removes [the vertical gap under that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510403/4-extra-vertical-pixels/22510610#22510610) (belonging to the inline elements which are positioned in their baseline), hence you could keep using it.

```css
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply put the two `<a>`s in separate `<div>`s and style these inner `<div>`s `display: inline-block;`

Alternatively, you could `display: inline-block` the two `<a>`s too.

Here's the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o8xnfujm/